# How to put a new line between buttons? PHP

Tags: php, newline

```
$form->addElement( new Element\Button (" Edit " , "button " ));

$form->addElement(new Element\Button);

$form->addElement(new Element\Button ( "Cancel " , "button"));
```

I used `\n` and `PHP_EOL`,but nothing works. The new line should be between the EDIT button and the new Element. 
Should I use HTML?

Comment: Yes use HTML `<br />`?

Comment: \n and php_eol will generate a return in the source code, not an html return. Use <br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use < br> between buttons in php style

```
$form->addElement( new Element\Button (" Edit " , "button " ));
echo "<br>";
$form->addElement(new Element\Button);
echo "<br>";    
$form->addElement(new Element\Button ( "Cancel " , "button"));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this statement for new line:

```
 echo '<br/>';
```